# swift - Problem with UITableViewCells and SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sdwebimage

I'm working on a project and I have a problem with UITableViewCells, they are having a strange behaviour when I load the viewcontroller and then when I scroll.

First of all when I load the viewcontroller I see this :

[image: ViewController original view]

And then when I scroll down, and up I see this (that it's what I want) :

[image: Objective ViewController]

Any idea of what's going wrong??
Here it's a part of the code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: //HEADER IMAGE
            return 200.0
        case 1: //VAMONOS BUTTON
            return 195.0
        case 2:
            if(more) {  //WITH SCALES
                if(flightScales.count == 0) {
                    return 165.0
                }
                else {
                    return CGFloat(flightScales.count * 205) + 110.0
                }
            }
            else {  //WITHOUT SCALES
                return 165.0
            }
        case 3:
            if(accomodationMore) {  //7LINE DESCRIPTION
                return 435.0
            }
            else {  //2LINE DESCRIPTION
                return 180.0
            }
        default:
            return 0.0
        }
    }
```

And the image load :

```
 if let image = selectedFlight.image {
                    let requestUrl = url + "api/vuelo/imagen/" + image
                    headerCell.destinationImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: requestUrl), placeholderImage:UIImage(named: "icon-placeholder"))
                }
                else {
                    headerCell.destinationImage.image = UIImage(named: "icon-placeholder")
                }
                headerCell.initialize(destinationLabel: selectedFlight.title!, countryLabel: selectedFlight.desc!)
```

Comment: What's the problem? Can you annotate the images so it's clear what the issue is?

Comment: @AshleyMills edited

Comment: @AshleyMills The problem is, that when I load the view controller i want the view be like the second photo, not the first

Comment: As a first step I’d recommend using auto sizing cells using auto layout, rather than hard coding the cell heights

Comment: @AshleyMills But in the case 2 I don't have any alternative than hardcoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
image.contentMode = .aspectFit //or .aspectFill
image.cliptToBounds = true
```